# Non-continuous linear functional over polynomials with inner product $\langle f,g \rangle = \int_{0}^{1} f(x)g(x)dx$

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces

Let $P(X)$ denote the set of polynomials $p:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$, I found that the functional $\phi:P(X) \to \mathbb{R}$ such that $p \mapsto p(0)$ is linear but does not correspond to an inner product $\langle \cdot, v\rangle$. All these is done with the inner product $\langle f,g \rangle = \int_{0}^{1} f(x)g(x)dx$.

According to Riesz-Fréchet theorem, it should be the case except if $\phi$ is not continuous or $P(X)$ is not a Hilbert space with the given norm. What is the problem in this case?

Comment: Well, $P(X)$ is not a Hilbert space.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Of course $P(X)$ is not a Hilbert space, so the theorem does not apply.

And regardless, it's clear that $\phi$ is not continuous: Let $p_n(t)=(1-t)^n$. Then you can check that $||p_n||^2=\langle p_n,p_n\rangle\to0$ although $\phi(p_n)=1$ (so in fact $\phi$ is not given by the inner product with any vector in the *completion* of $P(X)$; not being continuous, there's no reason it should be.)

Comment: any easy justification for $P(X)$  not being a Hilbert space? I don't think that  Stone-Weierstrass works here since $\int_{0}^{1}$ is not the uniform convergence metric

Comment: @Rodrigo If a sequence is Cauchy in the uniform norm it is going to be Cauchy in the norm that you have.

Comment: @orole What orole said: Say $p_n\to f$ uniformly and $f$ is not a polynomial. Then $||p_n-p_m||\to0$, but  there does not exist a polynomial $p$ with $||p_n-p||\to0$. (Because convergence in $L^2$ implies some subsequence converges almost everywhere, so if $||p_n-f||\to0$ and also $||p_n-p||\to0$ then $f=p$ almost everywhere, hence $f=p$ since $f$ and $p$ are continuous.)

Answer (score 1):

$P(X)$ is not an Hilbert space since it is not complete by Stone Weirstrass, every continuous function is a limit of a sequence of polynomials.

Answer (score 1):

$P(X)$ is for the set of $L^2$ functions, a bit like what $\mathbb{Q}$ is for $\mathbb{R}$...

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/952101)

Comment: @ArnaudMortier: Yes it does provide an answer (at least a hint) : $P(X)$ is not complete and dense into $L^2$, as is $\mathbb{Q}$ with respect to $\mathbb{R}$ and that is exactly why $P(X)$ is not a Hilbert space. Moreover $P(X)$ is countable as $\mathbb{Q}$ and $L^2$ is kind of the logic extension of $\mathbb{R}^n$ and then of $\mathbb{R}$... So this answer gives more : a glimpse into the beauty and the connection  between different mathematical concepts. So, where are my up votes? :D

Comment: Now that's an answer :)

Comment: @ArnaudMortier: Alright then! :)